# Recursive SQL in DB2

Tags: db2

I have the a table with the following structure :

path:
objectId
step
timestamp

For example

```
objectId    step    timestamp
 1          IN     2014-04-12
 1          OUT    2014-04-13
 3          OUT    2014-04-11
 3          PLACED 2014-04-10
```

I need to do a query the produce the following result:

```
ObjectId      steps
 1            IN,OUT
 3            PLACED,OUT
```

I tried the recursion as the following:

```
WITH TEMP(objectId,STEP,RN) AS
(
(   

SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT  SCE.objectId
    ,SCE.STEP
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  PARTITION BY  objectId order by timestamp ) as RN

    FROM KAP.path SCE 
    WHERE   SCE.STEP IN ('IN','PLACED','OUT')
) WHERE RN =1

)
UNION ALL 
(

SELECT * FROM (     
    SELECT SCE1.objectId
    , STEP
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  PARTITION BY  objectId order by timestamp ) as   RN1

    FROM TEMP ,  path SCE1
    WHERE TEMP.objectId = SCE1.objectId
    AND  SCE.STEP IN ('IN','PLACED','OUT')

)WHERE RN +1 = RN1

) 
) select * from TEMP ORDER BY 1;
```

but this query failed due to

> The fullselect of the recursive common table expression "DB2INST.TEMP" must be the UNION of two or more fullselects and cannot
>   include column functions, GROUP BY clause, HAVING clause, ORDER BY
>   clause, or an explicit join including an ON clause

could you please advise, how can i fix my query to give the desired output or any other idea more efficient?

Comment: Try removing the superfluous/unnecessary parentheses around the individual select. They are totally useless and might actually be a problem here: `with temp as (select ... union all select ...)` is enough

Comment: the same result , and it is useful as i want to get the rows with RN=1

Comment: Is `LISTAGG()` available in your version of DB2?

Comment: What version of DB2 are you on?  Disallowing `JOIN`s is extremely strange (every version I've used has allowed).  More importantly, it's likely also complaining about the `ORDER BY` in the windowing statement... which is probably also suboptimal as you keep recalculating it.  You _might_ be able to make it work better by defining an initial CTE that just calculates the row number, then recursive over that (instead of the initial table).

Comment: For more information about recursive SQL in DB2 please check this webminar https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/7637/105565